# How to start/stop Tomcat service remotely using Ant

Tags: ant

I'm following this link (http://raibledesigns.com/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=TomcatAntTasks) to try and figure out how to start/stop tomcat service remotely and currently I'm getting an error saying none of the taskdef class can be found. I already have ant installed, what else am I missing? And is the link a good way to start/stop tomcat service?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the catalina-ant.jar in your ant's lib directory.  It comes with Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

With ANT you don't need an external task. ;)

Simply use SSHExec task to start and stop (service or shell) and SCP task to copy WAR (or anything).

Quick, native and clean!

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the path of the ant jar?

```
<taskdef file="tomcatTasks.properties">
     <classpath>
        <pathelement path="${tomcat.home}/lib/catalina-ant.jar"/>
     </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

on tomcat 6 there is no server folder.